# How can I add a word boundary on this regex

Tags: javascript, regex

Using javascript

Normally this regex works fine but every so often I find due to a missing character or odd punctuation in the text picked up by OCR that it carries on in the text and picks up a much wider range of text.
What I want to do is ensure that it stops in the string at Paragraph 14 and doesn't go any further in the matching. I am searching through thousands of documents, which all have slight variations in the text afterwards so I need a way of stopping the search somehow.
How can I add a word boundary at Paragraph 14?

Also, in the string below, if the Paragraph 3(b) has brackets, it is captured in the group. But if it just has Paragraph 3 it is not captured.
In the below text, I expect it to pick up paragraph 3 and then stop searching when it reaches Paragraph 14.
Possible text options for the group capturing are:

> Paragraph 3
>
> Paragraph 3(b)
>
> Paragraph 10

Regex:

```
Para[a-z]+ 13\S+\s+E[\s\S]*?\(B\)\s["']Ret[a-z]+ Am[a-z]+["'].*?(Paragraph \S+[^.\s])
```

String:

> Paragraph 13. Elections and Variables - io. The following terms and Portfolio Transactions,
>   conditions of this Paragraph 13 of this Annex shall apply only with
>   Party B ("Bridge Agreement"): (a) Security Interest for as defined in
>   the Bridge Agreement between Morgan Stanley respect to Eligible Co. &
>   LLC and "Obligations". additional obligations: With respect to 
>   A: The term "Obligations" as used in this Annex includes the following
>   None. With respect to  B: None. (b) Credit Support Obligations.
>   (i) Delivery Amount, Return Amount and Credit Support Amount. (A)
>   "Delivery (B) "Return Amount" has the meaning specified in Amount" has
>   the meaning specified in Paragraph 3 this Annex. (C) Something else Paragraph 3(a)
>
> Paragraph 14. Elections and Variables - Transfer Timing. Paragraph
>   4(b)

Comment: Please specify programming language/tool you're using in tags

Comment: Please specify context. I doubt that you need such a complex regex for anything that simple.

Comment: Context is text picked up by an OCR. All the complexity is due to small OCR errors. ANd when there's an OCR error, the match pattern seems to extend to multiple,pages of a matching string. That's why I was thinking of a word boundary to stop it,. I mean, really the important part is the last capture group and the word boundary

Answer (score 0):

To capture paragraph with word suffix that might have parenthesis:

```
Paragraph (\w+|\(\w+\))
```

Limit your matched text this way: (lazy with max of 50 chars)

```
.{0,50}
```

Use a negative lookahead at the end of your regex: (newline followed by word paragraph)

```
(?!\nParagraph (\w+|\(\w+\)))
```

So combined your regex would end with:

```
.{0,50}(?!\nParagraph (\w+|\(\w+\)))
```

In your Regex

```
Paragraph (\w+|\(\w+\))\S+\s+E[\s\S]*?\(B\)\s["']Ret[a-z]+ Am[a-z]+["'].{0,500}(?!\nParagraph (\w+|\(\w+\)))
```

[image]

Comment: I couldn;t post all of this due to the long string but here's the problem I am having. When there is a spelling error, the regex expands to scan the rest of the document and picks up another paragraph 3 that is incorrect at the end. How can I make it stop at a word boundary like Paragraph 14 or maybe something else like a character limit of 500 characters? https://regex101.com/r/FSB5aW/1

Comment: Please post a source text and expected result.

Comment: link above -  In this string, the regex can't find a match at the first misspelt (B) "Retum Amount" so it just finds another "Return Amount" in the document, which I do not want it to. In this example, it should just find no match because I want to stop it searching after a certain string length or where Paragraph 14 is found, it should stop. I only want to search within Paragraph 13 or as an alternative, the first n hundred characters

Comment: @Gretel I updated solution with a couple of ideas you can plug into your regex.

Comment: Javascript does not support negative lookbehind, so it removed snippit.

Comment: Hmm. The 0,50 goes at the end of the regex? Doesn;t seem to be supported in javascript either https://regex101.com/r/FSB5aW/3

Comment: Replace the .*?(Paragraph \S+[^.\s]) at the end with new concept

Comment: In 'theory' is should give you up to 50 chars not followed by newline-paragraph.

Comment: Like this: Paragraph 13\S+\s+E[\s\S]*?\(B\)\s["']Return Amount["'].{0,50}(Paragraph \w+(?:\(\w+\))?)       Still not working hmm    I still need to capture digits and brackets following the word Paragraph

Comment: You do not want to capture the Paragraph at the end, yes? e.g. Paragraph 14.  You just want to match it?

Comment: WIthin the document there are say 20 sections called Paragraph 1 then some text, Paragraph 2 then some text. I only want to look for matches within Paragraph 13. But with my current regex, it searches the entire document and sometimes picks up a match in the wrong section due to spelling mistakes in Section 13.

Comment: OK. We are getting there.  \nParagraph \w+.{0,100}(?!\nParagraph)     This will match all text between paragraphs, as a rough start.

Comment: See updated answer.  I removed the hardcoded 13 and changed max size to 500

Answer (score 0):

Still not quite working for me. Let me add 2 simple examples.

> Paragraph 12 Paragraph 13 Paragraph 3(b) Paragraph 14 Paragraph 6

In this example it all works, It captures the group Paragraph 3(b) correctly.

Now, another example -

> Paragraph 12 Paragraph 13 Parablagr 3(b) Paragraph 14 Paragraph 6

In this example, there is a spelling mistake, so it captures Paragraph 6 incorrectly. 
Here I would need it to stop when it finds paragraph 14 and capture nothing.